# How can I convert datatype for argument passed into Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, casting

I have a MyFunction that may take several datatypes, which are all very similar. I just want to pass all these different types of data into MyFunction with multithreading and type cast in MyFunction. Is this something possible? Is using dictionary a good idea? Please advise.

```
Main(){
    Parallel.ForEach(objectType1, MyFunction)
    Parallel.ForEach(objectType2, MyFunction)
    Parallel.ForEach(objectType3, MyFunction)
}

MyFunction(object arg){
  Dictionary<string, object> d = (Dictionary<string, object>) arg;
  Type1 t1;
  Type2 t2;
  Type3 t3;
  if (d.Key == "Type1") {
        t1 = (Type1) d.Value;
        ProcessType1(t1);
  }
  else if (d.Key == "Type2") {
    t2 = (Type2) d.Value;
        ProcessType2(t2);
  }
  else if (d.Key == "Type3") {
    t3 = (Type3) d.Value;    
        ProcessType3(t3);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ProcessTypeX()` directly?

Comment: It seems like a foreach loop is missing in MyFunction?!  If not, Why use the Dictionary?  You should use a Tuple or a custom object maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
MyFunction (object arg) {
    if (arg is Type1) { ProcessType1(arg as Type1); }

    else if (arg is Type2) { ProcessType2(arg as Type2); }

    else if (arg is Type3) { ProcessType3(arg as Type3); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If (object is type)
{
var type1 = object as type
//Process
}
```

Not sure why anything else would be required.

You could also use a strategy pattern and send in IStrategy concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic method.  Perhaps like this:

```
    private void MyFunction<T>(T arg)
    {

    }
```

You could possibly even cut down on the number of `void ProcessTypeX(object arg)` methods that you have by making it generic and handling it all in one method call.  That would I suppose depend on the complexity of the methods themselves.